# NDK unable to see header .h files

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk

I am trying to compile an NDK project The project contains OpenCoreAMR library for audio compression. The structure of the jni folder is like this

/jni

```
/lib-flac

/libmp3lame

/liboggvorbis

/libopencoreamr <---- That where the compilation problem is occuring.
```

I can this error when I run `ndk-build NDK_LOG=1` in the /jni directory.

```
C:/Users/ADMIN/Desktop/EnjoderJNI/app/src/main/jni/com_nll_nativelibs_VorbisEncoder.c:149:3: warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 5 has type 'jlong' [-Wformat=]
[arm64-v8a] Compile++      : encoder <= com_nll_nativelibs_amr_wrapper.cpp
[arm64-v8a] Compile++      : encoder <= com_nll_nativelibs_amr_encoder.cpp
C:/Users/ADMIN/Desktop/EnjoderJNI/app/src/main/jni/libopencoreamr/com_nll_nativelibs_amr_encoder.cpp:4:47: fatal error: com_nll_nativelibs_amr_interf_enc.h: No such file or directory
 #include <com_nll_nativelibs_amr_interf_enc.h>
                                               ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [C:/Users/ADMIN/Desktop/EnjoderJNI/app/src/main/obj/local/arm64-v8a/objs/encoder/libopencoreamr/com_nll_nativelibs_amr_encoder.o] Error 1
```

I have no idea why it is saying the **com_nll_nativelibs_amr_interf_enc.h** is missing even though the file is right inside the directory.

I am using NDK r11C on Windows 10.

How can I resolve this problem?

**Android.mk** inside the /jni folder.

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LAME_LIBMP3_DIR     := libmp3lame
LIBVORBIS_LIBOGG_DIR    := liboggvorbis
LIBFLAC_DIR     := lib-flac
LIB_OPENCORE_AMR_DIR := libopencoreamr
LOCAL_MODULE        := encoder

LIBFLAC_SRC_FILES := \
    $(LIBFLAC_DIR)/ogg/src/bitwise.c \
    $(LIBFLAC_DIR)/ogg/src/framing.c \
    $(LIBFLAC_DIR)/flac/src/libFLAC/bitmath.c \
    $(LIBFLAC_DIR)/flac/src/libFLAC/bitreader.c \
    $(LIBFLAC_DIR)/flac/src/libFLAC/cpu.c \
    $(LIBFLAC_DIR)/flac/src/libFLAC/crc.c \
    $(LIBFLAC_DIR)/flac/src/libFLAC/fixed.c \
    $(LIBFLAC_DIR)/flac/src/libFLAC/float.c \
    $(LIBFLAC_DIR)/flac/src/libFLAC/format.c \
    $(LIBFLAC_DIR)/flac/src/libFLAC/lpc.c \
    $(LIBFLAC_DIR)/flac/src/libFLAC/md5.c \
    $(LIBFLAC_DIR)/flac/src/libFLAC/memory.c \
    $(LIBFLAC_DIR)/flac/src/libFLAC/metadata_iterators.c \
    $(LIBFLAC_DIR)/flac/src/libFLAC/metadata_object.c \
    $(LIBFLAC_DIR)/flac/src/libFLAC/ogg_decoder_aspect.c \
    $(LIBFLAC_DIR)/flac/src/libFLAC/ogg_encoder_aspect.c \
    $(LIBFLAC_DIR)/flac/src/libFLAC/ogg_helper.c \
    $(LIBFLAC_DIR)/flac/src/libFLAC/ogg_mapping.c \
    $(LIBFLAC_DIR)/flac/src/libFLAC/stream_decoder.c \
    $(LIBFLAC_DIR)/flac/src/libFLAC/stream_encoder.c \
    $(LIBFLAC_DIR)/flac/src/libFLAC/stream_encoder_framing.c \
    $(LIBFLAC_DIR)/flac/src/libFLAC/window.c \
    $(LIBFLAC_DIR)/flac/src/libFLAC/bitwriter.c \
    FLACStreamEncoder.cpp \
    FlacUtil.cpp 
LAME_LIBMP3_SRC_FILES := \
    $(LAME_LIBMP3_DIR)/bitstream.c \
    $(LAME_LIBMP3_DIR)/fft.c \
    $(LAME_LIBMP3_DIR)/id3tag.c \
    $(LAME_LIBMP3_DIR)/mpglib_interface.c \
    $(LAME_LIBMP3_DIR)/presets.c \
    $(LAME_LIBMP3_DIR)/quantize.c \
    $(LAME_LIBMP3_DIR)/reservoir.c \
    $(LAME_LIBMP3_DIR)/tables.c \
    $(LAME_LIBMP3_DIR)/util.c \
    $(LAME_LIBMP3_DIR)/VbrTag.c \
    $(LAME_LIBMP3_DIR)/encoder.c \
    $(LAME_LIBMP3_DIR)/gain_analysis.c \
    $(LAME_LIBMP3_DIR)/lame.c \
    $(LAME_LIBMP3_DIR)/newmdct.c \
    $(LAME_LIBMP3_DIR)/psymodel.c \
    $(LAME_LIBMP3_DIR)/quantize_pvt.c \
    $(LAME_LIBMP3_DIR)/set_get.c \
    $(LAME_LIBMP3_DIR)/takehiro.c \
    $(LAME_LIBMP3_DIR)/vbrquantize.c \
    $(LAME_LIBMP3_DIR)/version.c \
    simple_lame_lib.c \
    com_nll_nativelibs_LameEncoder.cpp \
    com_nll_nativelibs_Lame.c 
LIBVORBIS_LIBOGG_SRC_FILES := \
    $(LIBVORBIS_LIBOGG_DIR)/libvorbis/mdct.c    \
    $(LIBVORBIS_LIBOGG_DIR)/libvorbis/smallft.c \
    $(LIBVORBIS_LIBOGG_DIR)/libvorbis/block.c   \
    $(LIBVORBIS_LIBOGG_DIR)/libvorbis/envelope.c    \
    $(LIBVORBIS_LIBOGG_DIR)/libvorbis/window.c  \
    $(LIBVORBIS_LIBOGG_DIR)/libvorbis/lsp.c     \
    $(LIBVORBIS_LIBOGG_DIR)/libvorbis/lpc.c     \
    $(LIBVORBIS_LIBOGG_DIR)/libvorbis/analysis.c    \
    $(LIBVORBIS_LIBOGG_DIR)/libvorbis/synthesis.c   \
    $(LIBVORBIS_LIBOGG_DIR)/libvorbis/psy.c     \
    $(LIBVORBIS_LIBOGG_DIR)/libvorbis/info.c    \
    $(LIBVORBIS_LIBOGG_DIR)/libvorbis/floor1.c  \
    $(LIBVORBIS_LIBOGG_DIR)/libvorbis/floor0.c  \
    $(LIBVORBIS_LIBOGG_DIR)/libvorbis/res0.c    \
    $(LIBVORBIS_LIBOGG_DIR)/libvorbis/mapping0.c    \
    $(LIBVORBIS_LIBOGG_DIR)/libvorbis/registry.c    \
    $(LIBVORBIS_LIBOGG_DIR)/libvorbis/codebook.c    \
    $(LIBVORBIS_LIBOGG_DIR)/libvorbis/sharedbook.c  \
    $(LIBVORBIS_LIBOGG_DIR)/libvorbis/lookup.c  \
    $(LIBVORBIS_LIBOGG_DIR)/libvorbis/bitrate.c \
    $(LIBVORBIS_LIBOGG_DIR)/libvorbis/vorbisfile.c  \
    $(LIBVORBIS_LIBOGG_DIR)/libvorbis/vorbisenc.c   \
    com_nll_nativelibs_VorbisEncoder.c 


PV_TOP := $(LOCAL_PATH)/libopencoreamr/opencore-amr-main
PV_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/libopencoreamr/opencode-amr-oscl \
                    $(PV_TOP)/codecs_v2/audio/gsm_amr/amr_nb/common/include \
                    $(PV_TOP)/codecs_v2/audio/gsm_amr/amr_nb/common/src \
                    $(PV_TOP)/codecs_v2/audio/gsm_amr/amr_nb/dec/include \
                    $(PV_TOP)/codecs_v2/audio/gsm_amr/amr_nb/dec/src \
                    $(PV_TOP)/codecs_v2/audio/gsm_amr/amr_nb/enc/include \
                    $(PV_TOP)/codecs_v2/audio/gsm_amr/amr_nb/enc/src \
                    $(PV_TOP)/codecs_v2/audio/gsm_amr/common/dec/include

#include $(PV_TOP)/codecs_v2/audio/gsm_amr/amr_nb/common/Android.mk
#include $(PV_TOP)/codecs_v2/audio/gsm_amr/amr_nb/dec/Android.mk
#include $(PV_TOP)/codecs_v2/audio/gsm_amr/amr_nb/enc/Android.mk

LIB_OPENCORE_AMR_DIR := \
    $(LIB_OPENCORE_AMR_DIR)/com_nll_nativelibs_amr_wrapper.cpp \
        $(LIB_OPENCORE_AMR_DIR)/com_nll_nativelibs_amr_encoder.cpp\
    $(LIB_OPENCORE_AMR_DIR)/com_nll_nativelibs_amr_decoder.cpp 



LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(LIBFLAC_SRC_FILES) $(LAME_LIBMP3_SRC_FILES) $(LIBVORBIS_LIBOGG_SRC_FILES) $(LIB_OPENCORE_AMR_DIR)


LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(PV_INCLUDES)
LIBVORBIS_LIBOGG_NATIVE_FLAGS := -I$(LOCAL_PATH)/$(LIBVORBIS_LIBOGG_DIR)/include -I$(LOCAL_PATH)/$(LIBVORBIS_LIBOGG_DIR)/libvorbis/ 
LAME_LIBMP3G_NATIVE_FLAGS := -I$(LOCAL_PATH)/$(LAME_LIBMP3_DIR) -I$(LOCAL_PATH)/$(LAME_LIBMP3_DIR)/vector
LIBFLAC_NATIVE_FLAGS := -I$(LOCAL_PATH)/$(LIBFLAC_DIR)/config -I$(LOCAL_PATH)/$(LIBFLAC_DIR)/ogg/include -I$(LOCAL_PATH)/$(LIBFLAC_DIR)/flac/include -I$(LOCAL_PATH)/$(LIBFLAC_DIR)/flac/src/libFLAC/include -DVERSION=\"1.2\"


LOCAL_CFLAGS += $(LIBVORBIS_LIBOGG_NATIVE_FLAGS) $(LAME_LIBMP3G_NATIVE_FLAGS) $(LIBFLAC_NATIVE_FLAGS) \
        -I. \
        -fsigned-char \
        -DSTDC_HEADERS \
        -ffast-math

LOCAL_CPPFLAGS  += -std=c++11


LOCAL_LDLIBS := -L$(SYSROOT)/usr/lib -llog

ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH),arm)
    LOCAL_CFLAGS += -march=armv6 -marm -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfp
endif

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are using "" for referencing the missing .h file.

Most of the times developers make mistake of using <> for referencing the local files instead of ""

```
#include <> is used to include framework's/library files
#include "" is used to include your own local cpp header files
```

Comment: Changed <> to "" and it fixed the problem